# Rotating the complex number

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

Suppose we have square circumscribing circle $$|z-1|=\sqrt{2}$$ and one of its vertices is $$2+\sqrt{3}i$$ so what will be other vertices ?
I simple tried rotating half diagonal of square in anticlockwise direction , supposing we take center of circle as $z_o$ and known vertice as $z_a$ and other one as $z_b$ so 
$$\frac{z_a - z_o}{|z_a-z_o|}.e^{i.\frac{\pi}{2}} = \frac{z_b- z_o}{|z_b-z_o|}$$ which gave me 
$$( z_a - z_o).i= z_b- z_o$$ 
Now plugging in values gives me 
$$ (2+\sqrt{3}i -1).i +1= z_b $$ and finally $$1+i -\sqrt{3}$$ but answer is given as $$i -\sqrt{3}$$ , what is wrong here??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, trust your solution. The given solution is obviously wrong because its distance from the center of the circle is different compared to $z_a$.

You don't need to normalize anything. Just rotate around the center of the circle. The solution is simply to move to the origin, multiply, and move back. Let
$$z_a=2+\sqrt{3}i$$
and
$$z_0=1$$
All four vertices are simply
$$(z_a-z_0)\cdot\{1,i,-1,-i\}+z_0$$
which yields
$$2+\sqrt3 i,1+i-\sqrt3,-\sqrt3 i,1-i+\sqrt3$$
the second is your solution.

Comment: Very nice! One could also think of it in terms of coordinates so we have the center at $(1,0)$ and the vector $\begin{pmatrix}1\\\sqrt 3\end{pmatrix}$ being rotated by 90 degrees each time to have $\begin{pmatrix}-\sqrt 3\\1\end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix}-1\\-\sqrt 3\end{pmatrix}$ and $\begin{pmatrix}\sqrt 3\\-1\end{pmatrix}$ as vectors pointing from the center at $(1,0)$ to the other corners ...